# Where should I copy multimedia files on SD card?

Tags: sd-card, media-files

I have a Huawei P8 Lite to which I added an SD card.

Using Windows Explorer, I'm not sure where to copy multimedia files so that the files will be found by eg. VLC.

The "SD Card" item contains the following directories:

```
.backup
Android
backup
DCIM
HuaweiBackup
LOST.DIR
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Principially everywhere (except for `LOST.DIR`, `Android` and directories starting with a dot like `.backup`). Apart from that, you might wish to apply some "logic". Defaults are often:

- `Music`: for your music files (have sub-directories below that if you like)
- `Video`: for your video files
- `Pictures`: for photos etc.
- `Books`: for eBooks

Note that your Android device's camera stores its photos/videos below `DCIM`. The [media-scanner](/questions/tagged/media-scanner) will find your media files everywhere, unless you hide a directory and its contents by placing a `.nomedia` file into it. Several media players (and I assume VLC belongs into this category) also allow you browsing directories manually, independent from the device's media library.

Comment: Yeah, VLC scans the SD card and doesn't appear to depend upon mediaserver.

Comment: Glad to help, @Gulbahar – if it solved your issue, you can click the check-mark next to the answer to show that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your files to anywhere you want on your SD Card except the folders generated by the device like `LOST.DIR`, `Android`, and any other folder beginning with a dot like `.backup`. By default, any android device will search for multimedia files in all folders in the SD Card and recognize them using the system's **MediaScanner**. There is no specific folder, where you should copy to.

So for example, you can create these four folders in the root of your SD Card, and copy your files to them:

1. Music
2. Videos
3. Photos (sometimes people also like to put their photos in DCIM folder)
4. eBooks

Of course, you can name these folders anything you want and even create new ones as you like... If it happens that your device couldn't recognize any of your newly added files, just reboot your device and check them again, but that rarely happens.